# <function at 0x> while trying to define functions?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm pretty green at programming, so I don't really understand what's going on here. I'm trying to make it so that I can define multiple functions so that I can separate each one and call on them differently.
None of them are something you put in your own numbers for, just the function name and then it'd pop out without issue. That's what I'm going for here, but here's what I'm trying out:

```
def while_integer():
  i = 10
  while i < 1000:
    print(i)
    i += 10
```

Whenever I try to run it, I get "=> function while_integer at 0x7f5604d94bf8"
What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use parentheses when calling a function. Functions are first class objects in Python: you can pass them around to other functions and do other cool things with them. So the interpreter won't complain/crash if you *don't* use parentheses to call the function, it will just tell you that what you have is a function handle (i.e. the message that you got).

Do `while_integer()` instead if you want to *call* or *execute* the function.